# Retrieve MacOS calendar events using Python?

Tags: python, macos, calendar, eventkit

I am building a simple app using Tkinter with Python and am looking for a way to grab all my calendar events from my MacOS calendar (to then be sorted by datetime and printed, etc.). I know that Apple offers the EventKit framework for doing this, but I'm unsure how to incorporate this into a Python script.

All I need as the final result is a simple JSON or Python dictionary containing each event name and its corresponding datetime. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here.